# Sending a UNICODE string to A16 COMS Mainframe via TCP/IP

Tags: utf-8, tcp, communication, mainframe

I need to send a UNICODE string message to A16 COMS (Mainframe) via TCP/IP. What algorithm do I need , what transformation of a string. String can contain one or more UNICODE Characters.

While sending ASCII only based string I convert(map) it to EBCDIC and send via TCP/IP connection. I know that EBCDIC doesn't handle UNICODE Character. Besides, I can send via TCP IP only byte array, where in case of ASCII string one character maps to one array cell. In the  case of UNICODE character - it can occupy from 1 to 4 byte array cells.

The question is how do I send the UNICODE containing string to A16 Mainframe.

Further clarification:

When I run the code, the TCP client cannot receive any response. It passes timeout and gives an error. Increasing timeout does not help. C# can convert an UNC string to UTF-8 either using `System.Text.Encoding` or even with an algorithm - almost manually. Those are not a problem. Problem is that A16 COMS expects “one character = one byte”, (mapped to EBCDIC). And with UTF-8 one character may occupy 2, 3 or 4 cells of an array. Now EBCDIC mapping itself does not help, because EBCDIC is designed to work with non-unicode (ASCII based) strings.

I hope that someone whoever did this at some point in his career might read my post because not much can be done by figuring out. Can it be done with TCP Client and its NetworkStream? Send method has only array of bytes in its signature, but with utf-8 array of bytes can be so much longer than the limit.

It is a question asking to share experience, not knowledge.

Comment: You need to research unicode to byte mappings / character set conversions and then figure out how you want to deal with any characters not supported by your target environment. Please read [ask]; as is, your question is IMHO too broad. You could [edit] your question and add a [mcve] of what you've tried. What happens when you run your code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? If you didn't write any code, a web search is probably the best way to start; see above for keywords.

Comment: Hi, I'm on the same boat. did you try Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(37)

        Dim bytesSent As [Byte]() = ascii.GetBytes(request)